# def __str__ not working. Getting object reference except string

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()


def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Comment: Если вы объявили функцию `__str__` за пределами модели и никак не обращаетесь к ней, то конечно она не будет работать, ведь её никто не запускает

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Метод `__str__` должен быть объявлен внутри класса.